# Facebook developer want application to be visible in Application and Games

Tags: facebook

I have made a facebook App. It is a streamed music player. http://apps.facebook.com/viii_punkradio/

When I from my facebook go to Applications and Games to search for my app under new applications it doesnt turn up. Do anyone know if I have to register a new application in any way or have any other tips on how to make my application visible?

Answer (score 0):

You need 10 Monthly Active Users (MAU) and then wait a week or two to get indexed for search.